# .NET 7 HttpClient GetAsync() request empty headers value with basic authentication (Unauthorized)

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, httpclient, basic-authentication

I'm just sending request like this:

```cs
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBasicAuthentication("admin", "password");
var result = await client.GetAsync("url")
```

I get Unauthorized response. I am sure that my password and login are correct. In the debug result I see that request headers are empty after request.
The request is going to RabbitMQ Api

I tried send message instead of getAsync.Not working.

Comment: Have you tried the same request via some tool like Postman/curl?

Comment: Yes, via Postman works good. Even encoded authorization header is the same in both. But after GetAsync() all headers disappears. I'm checking it in debug by breakpoint

Comment: Please share the curl request generated by it (there is "code" button on the top right). Also pleas share the exception (JIC).

Comment: curl --location 'sensitive url' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Censored'

Comment: Now i tried just to copy C# code from Code in Postman and even that way this not working

Comment: Do you mean your headers are not empty before the request? Is `SetBasicAuthentication` your own extension implementation? Or in what package it is defined?